# Can String literals be passed from from a VF Page to VF Component then to Apex Controller to be modified?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have an interesting situation where I'm testing a VF Component by passing string literals from a VF Page. Some of these strings are then fed to a Custom Component Controller to be modified before being output. The strange thing is that the strings can't be modified by the custom component controller.

**Here's the code:**

### VF Page (for testing the VF component)

```
<apex:page>

    <c:Calendar description="A description \n with a new line \n again" xAltDesc="Something with \n and another \n new line break" dtstart="something" dtend="something" summary="A new summary" location="A location" />

</apex:page>
```

### VF Component

```
<apex:component controller="FormatController">BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
PRODID:-//Test
VERSION:2.0 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
CLASS:PUBLIC 
DESCRIPTION:<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!descriptionFormat}" /> 
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!xAltDescFormat}" /> 
DTSTAMP:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ}"><apex:param value="{! NOW() }" /></apex:outputText> 
DTSTART:<apex:outputText value="{!dtstart}" />
DTEND:<apex:outputText value="{!dtend}" />
SUMMARY:<apex:outputText value="{!summary}" />
UID:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}@test.com"><apex:param value="{! NOW() }" /></apex:outputText> 
LOCATION:<apex:outputText value="{!location}" /> 
LANGUAGE=en-us 
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
    <apex:attribute name="description" type="String" description="DESCRIPTION" assignTo="{!descriptionFormat}" />
    <apex:attribute name="xAltDesc" type="String" description="X-ALT-DESC" assignTo="{!xAltDescFormat}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="dtstart" type="String" description="DTSTART" />
    <apex:attribute name="dtend" type="String" description="DTEND" />
    <apex:attribute name="summary" type="String" description="SUMMARY" />
    <apex:attribute name="location" type="String" description="LOCATION" />
</apex:component>
```

### VF Component's Custom Controller

```
public with sharing class FormatController {
    
    public String descriptionFormat {
        get { return removeNewLines(descriptionFormat); }
        set { descriptionFormat = value; }
    }

    public String xAltDescFormat {
        get { return removeNewLines(xAltDescFormat); }
        set { xAltDescFormat = value; }
    }
    
    public FormatController() {}
    
    public String removeNewLines(String inputString) {
        
        return inputString.replaceAll('\n', '');
    }
}
```

The expected outcome is that both `descriptionFormat` and `xAltDescFormat` will have the `\n` characters removed. This code works as expected in execute anonymous Apex but not as shown above (the original strings from the VF Page are output).

Now the strange part is that when I add a custom controller for the VF Page and pass the strings as controller variables, everything works fine!

**More code:**

### VF Page Custom Controller

```
public class CalendarPageController {

    public String testDescription = 'A description \n with a new line \n again';
    
    public CalendarPageController() {
        
    }
    
    public String getTestDescription() { return testDescription; }
    
}
```

Modified VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="CalendarPageController">

    <c:Calendar description="{!testDescription}" xAltDesc="Something with \n and another \n like that" dtstart="something" dtend="something" summary="A new summary" location="A location" />

</apex:page>
```

Now `testDescription` works as expected, but because `xAltDesc` is a String literal, it still can't be modified.

All of this to say: is this expected behavior?

Comment: I'm surprised by this. Instead of using the custom page controller, try adding an `<apex:variable name="myDesc" value="stringwithlinebreaks"/>` and then use `<c:Calendar description='{!myDesc}"/>`

Comment: I'd just like to say... Excellent first question!

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior, though not clearly documented anywhere I can tell, as a literal cannot be modified, and so acts as a one-way data binding. If you need a "working copy", you'd want to write a setter method:

```
String descriptionFormatInternal, descriptionFormatOld;
public void setdescriptionFormat(String value) {
  if(value != descriptionFormatOld) {
    descriptionFormatInternal = descriptionFormatOld = value;
  }
}
```

Or, as you observed, setting up a variable in the parent page's controller will have the same benefit.

Comment: while I don't doubt what you are saying, when I try to replace a different string (lets say the word "new"), I was able to replace it with no issue. It only seems to be the `\n` where I see this behavior